# How to do an Augmented Reality SDK on our own

Tags: android, sdk, augmented-reality

Hi we are a small unit from Chennai having 3+ years of exp in Android programming. We have planned to move to **Augmented Reality** concept and we have decided to built the AR SDK from scratch! But we have no clue on where to start. We have already used KUDAN AND VUFORIA which are best at its sources but commercial. We know the principle behind the working concept of AR.

So what a SDK developer will plan before diving into coding? Kindly please dont close or downvote the question because as a 3+yrs experience we need some kind of more informations to achieve the task! Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know a bit more what this task require of you - you decided to do it from scratch without ANY effort estimation and cost estimation, because you do not know what is involved... This sounds like it might be a problem for you. I would strongly recommend making sure no AR open source SDK can assist you, since this is not a small project.

Now, if you insist... What I would suggest is to first set your goals - comparing to existing SDKs which you have examined, what do you want to achieve (performance-wise, memory-wise, API-wise, etc.).

Then, learn what feature-detection algorithms may be involved in order to achieve the required results, what type of system is required architecture-wise in order to meet the requirements. Design the architecture carefully, as the frame rate is the most critical issue usually on mobile AR apps. Also use the experience you got while trying to use other SDK-s - what was hard for you to use? What were you missing?
Once these are done, go and search for the technology to use - mainly, image processing library (such as OpenCV, and others).
Then, only then, you should start coding your SDK...

This is only the tip of the iceberg - you are up for a very big challenge.